# Connacting 4 monitors on 2 vido cards (1 on intel 3 on nvidia) ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to connect 4 monitors to my computer

Intel Graphics onboard x 1 monitor
Nvidia GTX 660         x 3 monitors

So far on clean install all 4 are working in a glitchy way,
so i update my nvidia drivers and only 2 of them were working.
And then ive tried to install bumblebee and things got way worse

can some one help me to find out how to make all my monitors to work fine

by the way they all work fine on Windows so its not a BIOS setup (i think)

*Bump*